# How can I vectorize this "for" loop in octave?

Tags: octave, vectorization, increment

I am working with an image and trying to get the HSV histograms.
I was trying to vectorize this piece of code:

```
for i = 1 : k
    Hh(H(i))++;
    Sh(S(i))++;
    Vh(Cmax(i))++;
endfor
```

H, S and Cmax are occurence arrays and Hh, Sh and Vh are the HSV histograms.

I have tried to vectorize like this:

```
Hh(H(1:k))++;
Sh(S(1:k))++;
Vh(Cmax(1:k))++;
```

But the problem is that it only does the incrementation once, so instead of having the number of occurences I only have a '1' where there is at least one value.

How can I vectorize that piece of code?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the `hist` or `histc` functions?

Comment: @beaker It's an assignment, I am not supposed to use hist or histc, I have to implement them

Comment: Then look at the code of `hist` or `histc`. Octave is free software, free as in freedom. One of those freedoms is the [freedom to study how the program works](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). And in your case, both functions are implemented as m files.

Comment: @carandraug I got my own implementation of the functions, but vectorizing is a big part of the exercise and I've tweaked a few things but I can't get around this for loop.

Comment: Have you looked at [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)? (Hint: `val` would be `1`)

Comment: @beaker managed to get a solution with accumarray. Thank you :D